# Getting current title of page and updating from nested component and updating in Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component called Notificiations.vue that is imported and used in the same parent component where my router-view is also being used.

Very basic example - my App.vue is something like:

```
<Template>
<Notifications></Notifications>
<router-view></router-view>
</Template>
```

Most of the individual pages that can be accessed with the router have a component that sets the page title like below:

```
metaInfo: function () {
            return {
                title: 'Leads - ' + this.view
            }
        }
```

What I'm wanting to do with Notifications.vue is whenever a new notification comes in, get the current title of the browser tab and just add in a (1) (or whatever number) to the front of it. I tried using regular Document.title to get the current title, but that is always returning undefined. What is another way I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have a data object in your notifications component.

A simplified version of Notification.vue

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    notifications: []
  },
  watch: {
    notifications (current, previous) {
      document.title = '(' + current.length + ')' + document.title.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
    }
  }
})
```

What we are doing here is watching the notifications object for changes. If it changes we are prepending the number of notification to the title of the document.

`document.title.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "")` this part is removing the current count of notifications prior to being updated with the new count.

Limitations to this approach:

If there are other (words) in parentheses in the title they will get stripped.

If the count of notifications is ZERO it will display (0) Title if the count is 1234 it will show (1234) Title. You may want to put some more checks in place to not show ZERO and perhaps do 9+ if length is > 9

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use Vuex to manage state.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    notifications: []
  },
  mutations: {
    load (state, notifications) {
      state.notifications = notifications
    }
  },
  actions: {
    load (context) {
      Vue.$http.get('/notifications').then(response = {
        context.commit('load', response.data);
      })
    }
  }
});

// Notifications.vue
new Vue({
  mounted () {
    // you will want to add more than just an interval. You will want to keep track of this and perhaps stop it if, for example, the user logs out.
    setInterval(function () {
      store.dispatch('load');
    }.bind(this), 1000)
  }
});


// Add to your router
metaInfo: function () {
  return {
    title: '(' + store.state.notifications + ')' + 'Leads - ' + this.view
  }
}
```

This was a quick example of how using Vuex would solve this problem. This is not tested and is for educational purposes only. Read more at https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: This is arguably the better approach and what I use in my larger applications.